# Website button logic to place order like Cameo "Book Order"

Tags: javascript, button, paypal, stripe-payments, logic

I want to set my website buttons up with logic to know which option is selected when the customer presses "Book now". Then, I would like the website to go to checkout where the customer can type their message in and pay using PayPal or another online payment platform. Here is a link to Cameo, which inspired this project: https://www.cameo.com/sar.rob?nodeId=actors%2Fbollywood&nodeType=category Any resources or help would be amazing!

Logic:
Have "Personal use" already selected. Allow customers to press "Business use" to change the option selected. Book now send the selected option to checkout.

[image: Example of what the buttons look like.]

Answer (score 1):

My approach will be to use radio buttons.

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form")

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let planOptions = new FormData(form)

  for (const selectedPlan of planOptions) {
    console.log(selectedPlan[1])
  }

  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.options label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.options input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}

.book-now {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <h3>Choose an option</h3>

  <div class="options">
    <input type="radio" name="planOptions" value="personalUse" id="personalUse" checked>
    <label for="personalUse">Personal Use</label>

    <input type="radio" name="planOptions" value="businessUse" id="businessUse">
    <label for="businessUse">Business Use</label>
  </div>

  <button class="book-now" type="submit">Book Now</button>

</form>
```

Checkout [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) for reference